# Abort long ajax call from a commandButton actionListener?

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I would like to be able to **stop the execution of a lengthy task** started with a commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton id="startBatch"value="Go" actionListener="#{batchController.sendBatch()}"ajax="true"  />
```

So in my Model I added a boolean "abort" and inside sendBatch() I added a check to stop the loop when the boolean becomes true:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= batch.size(); i++) {
    if (batchModel.isAbort()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

And in my XHTML I added a new button that calls a method that sets this boolean to true:

```
<p:commandButton id="abortBatchButton"
value="Abort"
actionListener="#{batchController.abort()}"
ajax="true"/>
```

The problem is that **abort() is called after the sendBatch() method is done.**

Is there a simple way to implement this ?

Comment: Try `async="true"` on the button which starts the batch. By the way, `ajax="true"` is default for `p:commandButton`.

Comment: Well, you know me by now :-) That worked, thanks. As usual, I'll ask you to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `p:commandButton`s use Ajax. However, multiple actions (requests) are queued and executed synchronically by default. So, if you have started a lengthy action, the next action will be processed when the previous actions are finished.

If you don't want to queue actions, you should use `async="true"` on the respective buttons.

In your case:

```
<p:commandButton id="startBatch"
                 value="Go"
                 async="true"
                 actionListener="#{batchController.sendBatch()}" />
```

I've removed `ajax="true"`, since it's default.